# HTTP Status 400 - Parameter conditions "" OR "" OR "" not met for actual request parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, controller

After uploading a excel file in Spring MVC Application, getting following error
HTTP Status 400 - Parameter conditions "" OR "" OR "" not met for actual request parameters

uses the following 3 methods definitions:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadExcelFile",params="filep1",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFiles(@RequestParam("filep1") CommonsMultipartFile file,
            Model p_objModel,
            HttpSession l_objHttpSession) throws IOException
```

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadExcelFile",params="filep2",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFiles2(
            Model p_objModel,
            HttpSession l_objHttpSession,MultipartFile file) throws IOException
```

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadExcelFile",params = "filep3",method=RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView upload(@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file,HttpSession session){  
            String path=session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

In JSP file configurations is as follows:

```
 <form action="uploadExcelFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Custom file:</p>
    

      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="filename">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file to upload</label>
    </div> -->
    
    
    <input type="file" name="filep1" id="myFile1">
    
   
    <input type="file" name="filep2" id="myFile2">
    
   
    <input type="file" name="filep3" id="myFile3">
  
    <div class="mt-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

spring-servlet.xml configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10485760"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Please help out on this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? I don't understand your setup.

Comment: I am trying to upload a excel file and getting the file details in controller(Spring MVC) for which I am using three different methods defined above. But none worked and getting error.

Comment: Still I don't get your setup? Why 3 methods? Why 3 fields in your form? Why? So many questions, and it looks already wrong by design what you are doing in the first place.

Comment: I am using three different ways to upload an excel file but none of them worked.

Comment: Trying to upload with an excel file in Spring MVC in 3 different methods/ways, but none of them worked.

Comment: Anyone, Please help on this.It is required for the project. What are the things required for uploading a excel file in Spring MVC, Please elaborate on this.Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What you have should work, however the thing with 3 files with 3 different ways is making it overly complex. Why on earth would yolu need that (or want that). Also what if someone submits 3 files, what do you expect will happen? Go back to the design board and find a better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum for the help !